# Form error int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QueryDict'

Tags: django, django-forms

Can someone help me out with the following error below and explain the issue? All I'm trying to do it populate a group with a query set, but upon submitting the form I get the following error...

****TypeError at /sms/addbatch
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QueryDict'****

**views.py**

```
def add_batch(request):
    # If we had a POST then get the request post values.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BatchForm(request.POST)
        # Check we have valid data before saving trying to save.
        if form.is_valid():
            # Clean all data and add to var data.
            data = form.cleaned_data
            groups = data['group'].split(",")
            for item in groups:
                batch = Batch(content=data['message'],
                              group=Group.objects.get(pk=item),
                              user=request.user
                              )
```

**form.py**

```
class BatchForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Batch


    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BatchForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            form_choices = Batch.objects.for_user_pending(user)
        else:
            form_choices = Batch.objects.all()

        self.fields['group'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=form_choices
        )
```

**models.py**

```
class BatchManager(models.Manager):
    def for_user_pending(self, user):
        return self.get_query_set().filter(user=user, status="Pending")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `request.POST` as the `user` parameter to your form. Do this:

```
form = BatchForm(data=request.POST)
```

```
#  first parameter ---v
def __init__(self, user=None, ...

#  first parameter ---v
form = BatchForm(request.POST)
```