# How do i solve a int() argument must be a string or number not 'querydict' django error?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have dynamically created a django form to achieve some custom behavior like so,

```
def partial_order_item_form(item):
    """dynamic form limiting optional_items to their items"""
    class PartialOrderItemform(forms.Form):
        quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'2', 'class':'quantity','maxlength':'5'}))
        option = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=OptionalItems.objects.filter(item=item),widget= forms.RadioSelect())

    return PartialOrderItemform
```

I go ahead to validate in my views like so,

```
def show_item(request,id):
    a = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = partial_order_item_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order.add_to_order(request,a)
    else:
        form = partial_order_item_form(item=id)
    context={
        'form':form,    
    }
    return render_to_response('item.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When i submit the form, i get `int() argument must be a string or number not 'querydict'` error.

I have looked at [int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QueryDict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649499/int-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-querydict) and [Form error int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QueryDict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568469/form-error-int-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-querydict) but still not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the request.POST query dict to:

```
OptionalItems.objects.filter(item=item)
```

Maybe you meant to pass something like request.POST['item_id']?